# Connect to Server with Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, vpn

I am setting up a VPN for Mac only. For those who don't know what a VPN is, click [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network).

I currently am at the stage where I set up a server in on foreign soil, and now I was wondering if there was a certain command in the Terminal or a method similar to that which connects a mac to that server, and allows the user to connect to the internet via the connection to that server (just like how  a VPN works).

I am fairly new at internet programming, and any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Eric

Comment: Setting up a VPN is not programming - try http://superuser.com or http://apple.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 0):

you could set up the vpn connection in the normal GUI Tools (System Preferences > Network) then take a look at the command line tool called "networksetup" .. it has a bunch of stuff for manipulating and connecting/disconnecting.

Comment: ok thanks for the advice, but what EXACTLY should I do in system preferences to set up this connection (i'd prefer to avoid using that though)

Comment: this will explain how to set the connection up ([link](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH14079)) .  This is probably your best approach since doing this programmatically is NOT a trivial task.  Once you have the settings done then if you really need to connect/disconnect via command line then use "networksetup" command.  After you have that all working then perhaps investigate a completely programmatic approach.